# Survival with only water but no food

Tags: human-biology

How long can the average, healthy adult human survive with only water?

Comment: this seems to be an opinion-based question. Also, it would be better to post your research as well as question. What sites are you talking about? Any papers? what is particular side of such survival are you interested in?

Comment: @aandreev this question is not opinion based. You cannot survive forever without food, at least as far as I know.

Comment: Definitely not opinion-based, actually a great question - but a dupe

Answer (score 0):

On average, it has been stated to be about five weeks however it differs from person to person based primarily on physical stats.

The process that would occur :

1. First food that remains in your stomach is digested
2. Readily available energy is then absorbed (This includes glucose, carbohydrates, anything that generally doesn't mean fat)
3. Your body then begins to convert fat into a source of energy. Your body would then begin to lose the resources to make protein and you would experience various effects such as night time blindness due to vitamin deficiencies
4. As you lose salt and other minerals the water you consume begins to build up in your cells via diffusion
5. You can either die of not enough energy or lack of protein or too many cells disintegrate from too much water

Source(s) : Biology book, Internet, Knowledge.